# Does Flash Builder 4.5 Standard allow variable inspection when debugging?

Tags: flash-builder

Is the variables tab shown below available in Flash Builder 4.5 Standard, or only in Premium?

[image: Flash Builder Debug Mode]
<sub>(source: [packtpub.com](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/Article-Images/flash-builder-6.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those debugging features are included in all versions (even student / teacher edition). 
You can see the differences  [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/buying-guide.displayTab2.html) (they have very little differences).